# Is there a method for adding both an onkeypress and onclick eventlistener together?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have two questions, somewhat related.

1) is is possible to combine the 2 below functions into 1 more streamline function, or must I simply create a function and call it inside both eventlisteners

```
input.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
   if (event.keyCode === 13) {
     // code here 
}
```

and

```
input.addEventListener("click", () => {
     // code here 
}
```

but that would essentially be duplication of code

2) is there a way to make a sort of simple/basic autocomplete menu (similar to google but nowhere near as powerful) based on the contents of an array? while typing in the input/search bar? For clarification, the w3schools example didnt work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can attach multiple events to single element.
For reference you can have a look at [mozilladocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('input')

elem.addEventListener('keyup', eventhandler, false);
//elem.addEventListener('click', eventhandler, false);// not sure about this event
elem.addEventListener('keydown', eventhandler, false);

function eventhandler(event) {
     if (event.keyCode === 13) { // you press enter you get alert 
     
        alert("hi");
     }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field">
```

Comment: but isn't keyup and keydown pretty much the same thing? They both stem from the same element, however, the button I wish to click is a different element entirely, so I was wondering if it's possible to tie them around the common link to the input?

Also, how do people do that snippet thing?

Comment: click event does.it works with input type text ,so I just gave an example of how to tie events together

Comment: What does the false at the end represent, I'm assuming true is also a possibility, what would that do

Comment: There's no `event.keyCode` for a `click` event.

Comment: @Anan When you write an answer, there is a button in the editor to open the snippets editor.

Comment: @Anan you pass three params in addEventListener(),third one is option  that specifies characteristics about the event listener.You can have a view at mozilla docs

Comment: @ShubhDixit so its just a completely optional component?

Comment: getting errors from the event.keyCode `Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals` when try to start the website with npm, the docs did not cover this

Comment: Umm I guess you are confused with frontend js and node js .Have a look at this-https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Answer (score 2):

Use a separate function that you call in both event listeners.

```
function doWhatIWant() {
    // code here
}

input.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
   if (event.keyCode === 13) {
     doWhatIWant();
}

input.addEventListener("click", () => {
     doWhatIWant();
}
```

Comment: this is what I had been doing, hoping for something a little more streamlined, seems that this is the best I'm going to get, however. Do you know any solution for the autocomplete or other similar things? wanted to avoid a dropdown because it is going to be huge (probably go off the screen), also the arrow ruins my aesthetic.

Comment: There are many auto-complete widgets, although some of them require jQuery (including, of course, the jQuery UI widgets).

Comment: got one working, however, it needs 2 submissions of the same data to work.

Comment: You should post a new question with this problem. It sounds like you're not using asynchronous code properly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the onclick eventListener and/or keypress eventListener directly to the button and having the other in your javascript, with the code content you want to run in its own function.

```
<input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="searchbar">
<button id="button1" onclick=foo()>Search</button>
```

```
    function foo() {
      searchResult = document.getElementById("input1").value;
      // code here
    }

    const searchBar = document.getElementById("input1");
    searchBar.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          // executes the button click
          document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
        }
    });
```

As for the autocomplete menu, I am unsure, but you could try turning it into a dropdown menu instead, however, this would likely make your need for the first part of the question invalid

Answer (score 0):

For #1 in your question, the other answers seem sufficient.

Just as an alternative you could use some modern JS to write something that adds listeners for an array of event names, and handle them in your handler function like this:

```js
// Handle keyup/click.
const handlerFn = e => e.type === 'keyup' ? e.keyCode === 13 && doSomething( e.type ) : doSomething( e.type );

// Did something.
const doSomething = type => console.log( `did something when ${type} triggered.` );

// Add handle/click listeners.
['keyup', 'click'].forEach( e => window.addEventListener( e, event => handlerFn( event ) ) );
```

```html
Click in here, or press enter.
```

In terms of #2, and implementing #1, yes, it's possible to have a search triggered as you type using an array of data to filter through.

As a very basic implementation, I would suggest writing a function to handle finding matches via regex matches in JS.  This could then be triggered from the keyup event, so it's filtered as a user types.

Here's an example of doing that with an input and search with some dummy data:

```js
// Some data to filter/search while typing.
const thingsToFilter = [
 {
  title: "One one one title",
  description: "description for this one one one"
 },
 {
  title: "Number 2",
  description: "2 is two."
 },
 {
  title: "Another Thing",
  description: "description for another things"
 }
];

// Function to match searches.
const findMatches = (stringToMatch, thingsToFilter) => {
 return thingsToFilter.filter(function(thingToFilter) {
  var regex;

  // Search for the stringToMatch from thingsToFilter.
  regex = new RegExp(stringToMatch, "gi");

  // Returns matches based on title or description.
  return thingToFilter.title.match(regex) || thingToFilter.description.match(regex);
 });
};

// Setup event listener for typing in input.
const pageSearch = document.getElementById("search");
pageSearch.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
 let val = pageSearch.value;

 if (val) {
  let matched = findMatches(val, thingsToFilter);
  if (matched) {
   let markup = matched.map(result => `<div class="search-result">${result.title}:${result.description}</div>` ).join("");
   document.getElementById("search-results").innerHTML = markup;
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
<div id="search-results"></div>
```

Comment: is there a way to make the `thingsToFilter` array able to be updatable? I have an autocomplete that will work so long as the array is pre-defined, however, I wish to download said array from a rest api to use, but if I download the array it does not seem to work

Comment: yes thingsToFilter can be whatever datasource you want it to be.  The example just shows an array of objects with "title" and "description", but whatever is returned can be filtered and sorted as you see fit.  If you run into issues with the datasource you're using - you could try opening a new question with some code for testing the response from the API and whatever code you're using.  My only guess would be the format of the datasource is just different than what is expected by the script.

Comment: yes I get that now, wasn't testing enough, the issue is it that it will not apply until the second time I access the search bar, just got to sort out the massive list it produces stretching my search bar to kingdom come

Comment: I have to pass it twice before it responds which is a pain (currently just keydown solves it, the problem is, that means its redownloading the array every single button press, not good for speed), dont suppose you know how to make it apply after one instance and only update if the values change?

Comment: It sounds like it starts, but then whatever happens next executes before the data is ready, and the second event triggered is reading the first call's data at that point.  I'd make sure you wait for the call to be done before executing further.  Another tip to help with resources is to debounce, I'd suggest something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce.  This article on CSS tricks explains more, and has an example of keypress with ajax: https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/#article-header-id-3

Comment: yeah it was just rushing ahead before the data was ready, a promise solved it